# web scraping twitter timestamp using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
dates = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_timestamp')
```

This only gives the current time and month like '4h', 'Mar 7'.
How can I get year-month-date using selenium??

Comment: We can't help you if you don't include the URL that you're trying extract data from.

Comment: ah sorry url is https://twitter.com/search?f=news&vertical=news&q=crypto&src=typd I think i need to use xpath but i am not sure..

Comment: Just added an answer to your question, I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver  = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://twitter.com/search?f=news&vertical=news&q=crypto&src=typd')
dates = [element.get_attribute('title') for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@class, "tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip")]')]
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['7:41 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '3:42 PM - 12 Mar 2018', '5:58 AM - 13 Mar 2018', '5:14 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '1:44 AM - 9 Mar 2018', '9:12 PM - 12 Mar 2018', '5:11 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '9:50 AM - 7 Mar 2018', '11:01 PM - 13 Mar 2018', '4:09 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '10:22 AM - 6 Mar 2018', '8:40 AM - 7 Mar 2018', '8:48 AM - 9 Mar 2018', '7:48 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '5:11 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '10:32 AM - 14 Mar 2018', '9:25 AM - 7 Mar 2018', '10:05 PM - 12 Mar 2018', '5:49 AM - 12 Mar 2018', '12:10 PM - 14 Mar 2018']
```

Comment: OMG!!! thank you!! could you explain the logic behind this? I dont understand what element does in this case

Comment: np @JakePark don't forget to mark the answer as an accepted answer if it is what solved your issue.